# Why is the Tabulator getRows() function not working?

Tags: tabulator

This seems like the simplest of requests but I can't seem to retrieve a set of rows from a Tabulator object.

Here's the code which instantiates the Tabulator object.........

```
function TabulatorInvitees(divId, companyName, userEmail) {
    try {
        var table = new Tabulator(divId, {
            columns: [
                {
                    title: "<div style='width:20%; float:left; text-align:left; color:blue; font-size:14px;'>Vendor Invitees</div>",
                    columns: [
                        { title: "Id", field: "Id", visible: false },
                        { title: "Added", field: "Added", visible: false },
                        { title: "Changed", field: "Changed", visible: false },
                        { title: "MarkedForExclusion", field: "MarkedForExclusion", visible: false },
                        { title: "Email Address", field: "Email", widthGrow: 1, responsive: 0, hozAlign: "center", editor: "input", visible: true },
                        { title: "First Name", field: "FirstName", widthGrow: 0.5, responsive: 1, hozAlign: "center", editor: "input", visible: true },
                        { title: "Last Name", field: "LastName", widthGrow: 0.5, responsive: 1, hozAlign: "center", editor: "input", visible: true }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    title: tabulatorAddUser(companyName),
                    field: "ManageRows",
                    widthGrow: 0.25,
                    responsive: 2,
                    hozAlign: "center",
                    formatter: "tickCross",
                    headerClick: function (e, row) {
                        row.getTable().addRow({ Id: 0, Added: true }, false);
                    },
                    cellClick: function (e, cell) {
                        tabulatorFreezeUnfreezeDelete(cell.getRow());
                    }
                },
            ],
            data: [],
            height: "100%",
            layout: "fitColumns",  // required when using 'widthGrow'
            placeholder: tabulatorPlaceholder(companyName), //display message to user on empty table
            reactiveData: true, //enable reactive data
            responsiveLayout: "collapse",
            rowContextMenu: tabulatorContextMenu(),
        });
        table.on("rowTapHold", function (e, row) {
            // from Tabulator documentation: "The rowTapHold event is triggered when a user taps on a row on a touch display and holds their finger down for over 1 second."
            //e - the tap event object
            //row - row component
            tabulatorContextMenu();
        });
        table.on("tableBuilt", function () {
            if (companyName.length > 0) {
                table.setData(getDataSync({ caseSelector: "VendorMgmt_EmployeeList", companyCode: companyName, userEmail: userEmail }));
            }
            else {
                table.setData([]);
            }
        });
    }
    catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}
```

The setData() function makes a call to a database function which returns three rows, similar to the following:

[image]

The following JQuery function is called when a radio button is clicked....

```
        $(".vendorStatus").click(function (e) {
            const status = e.target.value;
            const tbls = Tabulator.findTable("#divVendorEmployees");
            const tbl = tbls[0];
            const tblRows = tbl.getRows();

            console.log("tbls.length", tbls.length);
            console.log("tblRows", tblRows);

        });
```

The browser console indicates a table has been found (tbls.length = 1) but the tblRows array is empty:

[image]

I see the three rows in my Tabulator but I am not able to recall them programmatically. It seems like a simple problem which should have a simple answer.

I am using the most recent version of Tabulator (v5.4).

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After much searching, I finally came to the realization the DOM element associated with the Tabulator instance must be managed when attempting to refresh or replace data.  I've implemented a method which allows me to delete and rebuild the DOM element each time I need to save data to my database and subsequently refresh my Tabulator instance.

Here's the code...

```
function refreshTabulatorObject(obj) {
    let parentId = obj.parentId;
    let childId = obj.childId;
    //Empty and remove the current version of the [Tabulator] object.
    const tables = Tabulator.findTable(childId);
    if (tables.length > 0) {
        var table = Tabulator.findTable(childId)[0];
        table.setData([]);
    }
    //Remove the existing <div> from the DOM.
    $(childId).remove();
    //Re-create the <div> element for the [Tabulator] object and append it to the DOM.
    var parentDiv = document.getElementById(parentId);
    parentDiv.innerHTML = "";
    var childDiv = document.createElement("div");
    childDiv.setAttribute("id", childId);
    parentDiv.appendChild(childDiv);
    //Re-create the [Tabulator] object.
    TabulatorInvitees("#" + childId, obj.companyName);
}
```

I'm sure those of you with a more intimate knowledge of Tabulator would likely suggest a more elegant method, however, this one appears to work and I've already spent far more time on this issue that I had anticipated.  Unfortunately, elegance is not a luxury I can afford at this point.

I hope this solution might be of help to some other struggling soul.